# Cosine distance between sparse matrices

Tags: python, matrix, sparse-matrix

I'm trying to understand how to use the `csr_matrix` API along with its `cosine` functionality, and I'm running into `dimension mismatch` issues.

I have the following two (3,3) matrices:

```
a = scipy.sparse.csr_matrix(np.reshape(np.arange(9), (3,3)))
b = scipy.sparse.csr_matrix(np.reshape(np.arange(9)*2+5, (3,3)))
```

And I want to compute the cosine similarity (or cosine distance) from `a[0]` and `b[0]` a-la `cosine(a[0], b[0])`.

If I print out the dimensions of `a[0], b[0]` I get:

```
(<1x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 2 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>,
 <1x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 3 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>)
```

So their dimension matches.  But trying `cosine(a[0], b[0])` results in `ValueError: dimension mismatch`.  Any ideas why?

Comment: probably you need to transpose one of the vectors

Comment: @incBrain: transposing doesn't change the resulting error.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the right function? 

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html

Interestingly, this documentation page doesn't have a cosine function, even though there is one for sine and tangent and such. But the format is 'sin' and 'tan' making me think you want to use 'cos()' instead of 'cosine()'. What are you importing? There are cos and cosine functions all over numpy/scipy and the math package

Comment: @kingledion: I'm importing `from scipy.spatial.distance import cosine`

Comment: also see that your `a[0]` has 2 elements and `b[0]` has 3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the problem is that numpy.dot() is not aware of sparse matrices, per here: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html

When I run

```
>>> scipy.spatial.distance.cosine(a[0], b[0])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/scipy/spatial/distance.py", line 303, in cosine
    return (1.0 - (np.dot(u, v.T) / \
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/scipy/sparse/base.py", line 287, in __mul__
    raise ValueError('dimension mismatch')
ValueError: dimension mismatch
```

The error is in np.dot(), which doesn't understand the csr_matrix object that has been passed as an argument. This can be fixed by:

```
>>> scipy.spatial.distance.cosine(a[0].toarray(), b[0].toarray())
array([[ 0.10197349]])
```

Obviously not the answer you were looking for, by converting to a dense array you lose the performance advantages, but at least that is what is causing your problem.

Comment: it seems like I can get past the `cosine()` issue by just calculating it myself using the built in `.multiply()` methods in the `csr_matrix` api.  your solution also works though, so I'll mark as correct.